# x86 protected mode interrupts causes triple fault

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, qemu, osdev

I am making a OS and I am setting up my IDT. The IDT init processes without making the cpu panic (I think that should mean the IDT was set up).

I have already checked the osdev IDT debug, and looked into a few OS's IDTs (tetris-OS and SOSO), also checked that my gdt is the same as a working OS and understand what it does, but still can't get interrupts working. Here are some of my files

Qemu logs:

```
SMM: enter
EAX=00000001 EBX=00000000 ECX=02000000 EDX=02000628
ESI=0000000b EDI=02000000 EBP=00014b40 ESP=00006c60
EIP=000eafe4 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6180 00000037
IDT=     000f61be 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000080 CCD=00000001 CCO=LOGICB
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=00000001 EBX=00000000 ECX=02000000 EDX=02000628
ESI=0000000b EDI=02000000 EBP=00014b40 ESP=00006c60
EIP=000eafe4 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6180 00000037
IDT=     000f61be 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000000 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7d6b ECX=00001234 EDX=00006cff
ESI=00006cb8 EDI=07fbecc0 EBP=00006c78 ESP=00006c78
EIP=00007d6a EFL=00000006 [-----P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =d980 000d9800 ffffffff 008f9300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 008f9b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
GS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000004 CCD=00006c78 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7d6b ECX=00001234 EDX=00006cff
ESI=00006cb8 EDI=07fbecc0 EBP=00006c78 ESP=00006c78
EIP=000f7d6b EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6180 00000037
IDT=     000f61be 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000000 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007d85 ECX=00005678 EDX=07fa8f80
ESI=000e8c80 EDI=07fbecc0 EBP=00006c78 ESP=00006c78
EIP=000f7d84 EFL=00000012 [----A--] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6180 00000037
IDT=     000f61be 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000010 CCD=00006c64 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007d85 ECX=00005678 EDX=07fa8f80
ESI=000e8c80 EDI=07fbecc0 EBP=00006c78 ESP=00006c78
EIP=00007d85 EFL=00000006 [-----P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =d980 000d9800 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000004 CCD=00000001 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7d6b ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=0000699e EDI=07fbecc0 EBP=0000695e ESP=0000695e
EIP=00007d6a EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =d980 000d9800 ffffffff 008f9300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 008f9b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
GS =ca00 000ca000 ffffffff 008f9300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=0000695e CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7d6b ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=0000699e EDI=07fbecc0 EBP=0000695e ESP=0000695e
EIP=000f7d6b EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6180 00000037
IDT=     000f61be 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000000 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007d85 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000005
ESI=00000000 EDI=07fbecc0 EBP=0000695e ESP=0000695e
EIP=000f7d84 EFL=00000012 [----A--] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6180 00000037
IDT=     000f61be 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000010 CCD=0000694a CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007d85 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000005
ESI=00000000 EDI=07fbecc0 EBP=0000695e ESP=0000695e
EIP=00007d85 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =d980 000d9800 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =ca00 000ca000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000001 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7d6b ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=00006998 EDI=07fbecc0 EBP=00006958 ESP=00006958
EIP=00007d6a EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =d980 000d9800 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =ca00 000ca000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00006958 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7d6b ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=00006998 EDI=07fbecc0 EBP=00006958 ESP=00006958
EIP=000f7d6b EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6180 00000037
IDT=     000f61be 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000000 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007d85 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000003
ESI=07f91350 EDI=07fbecc0 EBP=00006958 ESP=00006958
EIP=000f7d84 EFL=00000016 [----AP-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6180 00000037
IDT=     000f61be 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000014 CCD=00006944 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007d85 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000003
ESI=07f91350 EDI=07fbecc0 EBP=00006958 ESP=00006958
EIP=00007d85 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =d980 000d9800 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =ca00 000ca000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000001 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7d6b ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=0000699e EDI=07fbecc0 EBP=0000695e ESP=0000695e
EIP=00007d6a EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =d980 000d9800 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =ca00 000ca000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=0000695e CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7d6b ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=0000699e EDI=07fbecc0 EBP=0000695e ESP=0000695e
EIP=000f7d6b EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6180 00000037
IDT=     000f61be 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000000 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007d85 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000005
ESI=00000000 EDI=07fbecc0 EBP=0000695e ESP=0000695e
EIP=000f7d84 EFL=00000012 [----A--] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6180 00000037
IDT=     000f61be 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000010 CCD=0000694a CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007d85 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000005
ESI=00000000 EDI=07fbecc0 EBP=0000695e ESP=0000695e
EIP=00007d85 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =d980 000d9800 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =ca00 000ca000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000001 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7d6b ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=00006998 EDI=07fbecc0 EBP=00006958 ESP=00006958
EIP=00007d6a EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =d980 000d9800 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =ca00 000ca000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00006958 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7d6b ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=00006998 EDI=07fbecc0 EBP=00006958 ESP=00006958
EIP=000f7d6b EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6180 00000037
IDT=     000f61be 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000000 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007d85 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000003
ESI=07ef1350 EDI=07fbecc0 EBP=00006958 ESP=00006958
EIP=000f7d84 EFL=00000016 [----AP-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6180 00000037
IDT=     000f61be 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000014 CCD=00006944 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007d85 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000003
ESI=07ef1350 EDI=07fbecc0 EBP=00006958 ESP=00006958
EIP=00007d85 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =d980 000d9800 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =ca00 000ca000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000001 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
Servicing hardware INT=0x08
Servicing hardware INT=0x0e
Servicing hardware INT=0x0e
Servicing hardware INT=0x0e
Servicing hardware INT=0x0e
Servicing hardware INT=0x0e
     0: v=00 e=0000 i=1 cpl=0 IP=0008:0000000000001780 pc=0000000000001780 SP=0010:000000000008fff0 env->regs[R_EAX]=0000000000000000
EAX=00000000 EBX=00007d7f ECX=00000020 EDX=000003d5
ESI=00000000 EDI=000003d5 EBP=0008fff0 ESP=0008fff0
EIP=00001780 EFL=00000087 [--S--PC] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     00007cd3 00000017
IDT=     10050009 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000fa0 CCD=fffff06c CCO=SUBL
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0xffffffff new 0xd
     1: v=0d e=0002 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:0000000000001780 pc=0000000000001780 SP=0010:000000000008fff0 env->regs[R_EAX]=0000000000000000
EAX=00000000 EBX=00007d7f ECX=00000020 EDX=000003d5
ESI=00000000 EDI=000003d5 EBP=0008fff0 ESP=0008fff0
EIP=00001780 EFL=00000087 [--S--PC] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     00007cd3 00000017
IDT=     10050009 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000fa0 CCD=fffff06c CCO=SUBL
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0xd new 0xd
     2: v=08 e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:0000000000001780 pc=0000000000001780 SP=0010:000000000008fff0 env->regs[R_EAX]=0000000000000000
EAX=00000000 EBX=00007d7f ECX=00000020 EDX=000003d5
ESI=00000000 EDI=000003d5 EBP=0008fff0 ESP=0008fff0
EIP=00001780 EFL=00000087 [--S--PC] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     00007cd3 00000017
IDT=     10050009 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000fa0 CCD=fffff06c CCO=SUBL
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0x8 new 0xd
```

The first check_exeption in the logs is `check_exception old: 0xffffffff new 0xd`

Idt.c:

```
#include "idt.h"

__attribute__((aligned(8)))
static idt_t  idt[31];   // Defines 32 idts
static idtr_t idtr;      // Makes a idtr

extern void flush_idt(u32int idt);

void set_idt(int vector, u32int offset) {
    //vector -= 11; // Used gdb to debug, the idt[vector] always points to the idt that is 11 farther
    idt[vector].low         = low_16(offset);   // (u16int)(((offset) >> 16) & 0xFFFF)
    idt[vector].selector    = 0x08;             // Sector
    idt[vector].zero        = 0;                // Reserved
    idt[vector].type        = 0x8e;             // ISR = 0x8E
    idt[vector].high        = high_16(offset);  // (u16int)((offset) & 0xFFFF)
}

void init_idt() {
    // Wrote these functions by hand to avoid errors
    set_idt(0 , (u32int) isr_0 );
    set_idt(1 , (u32int) isr_1 );
    set_idt(2 , (u32int) isr_2 );
    set_idt(3 , (u32int) isr_3 );
    set_idt(4 , (u32int) isr_4 );
    set_idt(5 , (u32int) isr_5 );
    set_idt(6 , (u32int) isr_6 );
    set_idt(7 , (u32int) isr_7 );
    set_idt(8 , (u32int) isr_8 );
    set_idt(9 , (u32int) isr_9 );
    set_idt(10, (u32int) isr_10);
    set_idt(11, (u32int) isr_11);
    set_idt(12, (u32int) isr_12);
    set_idt(13, (u32int) isr_13);
    set_idt(14, (u32int) isr_14);
    set_idt(15, (u32int) isr_15);
    set_idt(16, (u32int) isr_16);
    set_idt(17, (u32int) isr_17);
    set_idt(18, (u32int) isr_18);
    set_idt(19, (u32int) isr_19);
    set_idt(20, (u32int) isr_20);
    set_idt(21, (u32int) isr_21);
    set_idt(22, (u32int) isr_22);
    set_idt(23, (u32int) isr_23);
    set_idt(24, (u32int) isr_24);
    set_idt(25, (u32int) isr_25);
    set_idt(26, (u32int) isr_26);
    set_idt(27, (u32int) isr_27);
    set_idt(28, (u32int) isr_28);
    set_idt(29, (u32int) isr_29);
    set_idt(30, (u32int) isr_30);
    set_idt(31, (u32int) isr_31);

    idtr.base  = (u32int) &idt[0];              // Assigns the position of idt[0] to idtr.base
    idtr.limit = sizeof(idt_t) * 32 - 1;        // According to the intel IA-32 manuel, all idts are 8 bytes big
    flush_idt((u32int) &idtr);
    //__asm__ __volatile__ ("lidt %0" :: "m" (idtr)); // Loads the IDTR
}
```

int.asm:

```
[BITS 32]
[EXTERN int_handler]

int_get:
    SAVE_REGS
    call int_handler
    RESTORE_REGS
    add esp, 8     ; deallocate the error code and the interrupt number
    iret           ; pops CS, EIP, EFLAGS and also SS, and ESP if privilege change occurs

%macro isr_err 1
GLOBAL isr_%1
isr_%1:
    push %1
    jmp int_get
%endmacro

%macro isr_no_err 1
GLOBAL isr_%1
isr_%1:
    push 0
    push %1
    jmp int_get
%endmacro

isr_no_err 0
isr_no_err 1
isr_no_err 2
isr_no_err 3
isr_no_err 4
isr_no_err 5
isr_no_err 6
isr_no_err 7
isr_err    8
isr_no_err 9
isr_err    10
isr_err    11
isr_err    12
isr_err    13
isr_err    14
isr_no_err 15
isr_no_err 16
isr_err    17
isr_no_err 18
isr_no_err 19
isr_no_err 20
isr_no_err 21
isr_no_err 22
isr_no_err 23
isr_no_err 24
isr_no_err 25
isr_no_err 26
isr_no_err 27
isr_no_err 28
isr_no_err 29
isr_err    30
isr_no_err 31

%macro  SAVE_REGS 0
        pushad
        push ds ;those registers are 16 bit but they are pushed as 32 bits here
        push es
        push fs
        push gs

        push ebx
        mov bx, 0x10 ; load the kernel data segment descriptor
        mov ds, bx
        mov es, bx
        mov fs, bx
        mov gs, bx
        pop ebx
%endmacro

%macro  RESTORE_REGS 0
        pop gs
        pop fs
        pop es
        pop ds
        popad
%endmacro

global flush_idt
flush_idt:
    mov eax, [esp + 4]
    lidt [eax]
    ret
```

isr.c:

```
#include "isr.h"
#include "../kernel/functions.h"

void int_handler(u8int error, u8int interupt) {
    char* str = "0";    // Turns one digit ints to strings, enough for now
    *str += interupt;
    kprint(str);// Prints the int
}
```

If you need any more files you can see https://www.github.com/cheyao/OS

Comment: According to the log shown, your IDT is bogus: `IDT=10050009 00000000`.

Comment: How can I fix that?

Comment: Use a debugger. Put a breakpoint on the `lidt [eax]`. Verify it's loading the correct values. If not, work backwards to see why.

Comment: What should I use to debug asm? I can only got gdb to work for C files.

Comment: @cyao you can use gdb to debug asm code also. connect gdb to qemu with your kernel through some defined host:port. set breakpoint to particular line. It can be more complicated because to specify the breakpoint you need to tell gdb the address of it. and than follow the rip/eip/ip instruction pointer. yes, it's not very convenient... some steps from here partially can be helpful https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/gdb.html#:~:text=QEMU%20supports%20working%20with%20gdb,like%20JTAG%20on%20real%20hardware.

Comment: gdb works fine for assembly as well. You can also use the bochs built in debugger which has some useful features for system stuff. I believe [qemu monitor](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/monitor.html) can also disassemble and examine memory but you might need to put an endless loop before the `lidt` since it does not support breakpoints.

Comment: I happened to glance at your Makefile and I see you are compiling as 64-bit code, but you only put the processor in 32-bit protected mode. That won't work. You would have to put the processor in 64-bit long mode, or you'd have to consider using the `-m32` option when compiling; the `-melf_i386` option when linking; and `-f elf32` when using NASM to build as 32-bit. If making a 32-bit kernel you may be better off just getting an i686-elf (32-bit) cross compiler.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks you so much! It solved my problem! (that wasted me 3 weeks lol)

Comment: Don't edit "solved" into the title.  Post an answer and accept it if you want the system to show it as having been solved.  Or just leave it; your last comment is fine.

Comment: okk ill just post a anser and give credit to him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is now solved thanks to Michael Petch (Ansered in the comments)

I was using x86_64-elf-gcc to compile 32 bit code and didn't add the flag `m-32` so it was outputting 64 bit code